# Is "Tenor" okay?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I came across an advertisement which reads as follows:
[image]

As one may find, the advertisement uses the word "Tenor" to say that the Bond would have a term (or duration) of 8 years.

Is "Tenor" okay in the advertisement?

How are "tenor", "duration" and "term" different?

Would not the word-choice of "duration" or "term" have been better?

Comment: I agree with you, Dinesh. "Term" would be much better.

Comment: Note that "duration" in finance conveys a different concept: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/duration.asp

Comment: I think this question should be more properly asked here: http://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think they meant [_tenure_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tenure), but they should more properly use [_term_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/term).

Comment: Do you even check all the spellings and tags when you suggest an edit? Do you read all the sentences to see whehter they make sense? http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/338291/revisions

Comment: @Rathony I admit that I am not perfect. I slipped and did not correct the word "diner". http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/338291/revisions But, there exists mistake in your edit even. The title of the question you edited reads:'Is this grammatically incorrect to use "It was double the pleasure..."'. But, the last sentence of the question reads: 'Is this grammatically incorrect to use "it was double the pleasure..."?' Both the title and the last sentence are intended to be the same sentence, but one use "It" and the other "it", one ends without "?" and the other with "?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not commonly used, but it actually refers to the time to expiry:

***[Tenor](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tenor.asp)***:

> - ***Tenor in finance can have multiple usages, but it most commonly refers to the amount of time left for the repayment of a loan or until a financial contract expires.***
> - It is most commonly used for nonstandardized contracts, such as foreign exchange and interest rate swaps, while the term maturity is usually used to express the same concept for government bonds and corporate bonds. Tenor can also refer to the payment frequency on an interest rate swap.

(Investopedia)

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a government, municipality or corporate bond, you have to use '[maturity](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/maturity.asp?ad=dirN&qo=investopediaSiteSearch&qsrc=0&o=40186)':

> Maturity is the period of time for which a financial instrument remains outstanding. Maturity refers to a finite time period at the end of which the financial instrument will cease to exist and the principal is repaid with interest. The term is most commonly used in the context of fixed income investments, such as **bonds** and deposits.

The word '[tenor](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tenor.asp)' is used for a loan.

[Investopedia.com]

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that the meaning of words is different in different parts of the world.

The ad you have shown is clearly from India with Roman Hindi on top.

In India (and Pakistan) the word "tenor" is actually more easily understood than the word "term";as the word "term" can be used in many varied constructions the meaning of which may not be immediately graspable to people who learn English as as second or third language.

That said the word "term" might have been better, but, from an advertising point-of-view you want more people to understand your message; so grammar can sometimes be overlooked.